# How to implement 2FA using the django-two-factor-auth package for a specific admin site within a project containing multiple independent admin sites?

Tags: django, django-admin, multi-factor-authentication, django-two-factor-auth

As stated in the title, I am trying to implement Twilio SMS 2FA only for one of the multiple independent admin sites that I have, but I have not found any relevant documentation for this scenario and the implementation guide does not provide any info. Has anyone successfully implemented this scenario? Thank you in advance!

I tried following the steps indicated in the documentation as well as following some online tutorials but they all point to how it is implemented for the default admin site and my attempts have been unsuccessful so far.